# Retrofit continuous query not working properly in mobile network

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using retrofit for parsing JSON from Api. When i am using mobile network (Not WIFI) then continuously making query to retrieve response from api sometimes getting time out error.

**Code :**

```
userLogin("Username").
                enqueue(new RetrofitCallback<PatientModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(PatientModel result) {
                        if (null != result) {
                            loginResponse(result);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int code, String msg) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onThrowable(Throwable t) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        hideProgress();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must increase time out. Could you try this :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
            .create();
    okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL).client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
    apiService = retrofit.create(IService.class);
```

Comment: Yes i am using TimeOut for 1 minute.